Moviepy in cloud function works in test mode but not when published through https
I have a google cloud function where I use moviepy to crop a video and it works in test mode but not when published in https. Here is the code I am using
# main.py

import requests
import moviepy.editor as mpy
from google.cloud import storage
import os
import json
from datetime import datetime
import traceback

# Google Cloud Storage configuration
bucket_name = 'bucketname'  # Update with your bucket name
storage_client = storage.Client()

def crop_video(video_path, output_path, resolution):
    # Open the video file using moviepy
    clip = mpy.VideoFileClip(video_path)

    # Calculate crop parameters based on the resolution
    if resolution == '9:16':
        (w, h) = clip.size
        crop_width = h * 9 / 16
        x_center = w / 2
        y_center = h / 2
        # Calculate crop box coordinates
        x1 = int(x_center - crop_width / 2)
        x2 = int(x_center + crop_width / 2)
        y1 = 0
        y2 = h
        # Apply crop
        cropped_clip = clip.crop(x1=x1, y1=y1, x2=x2, y2=y2)
    else:
        raise ValueError('Invalid resolution. Must be "9:16".')

    # Write the cropped video to the output file
    cropped_clip.write_videofile(output_path, codec="libx264", audio_codec="aac", threads=5, preset="ultrafast")

def crop(request):
    try:
        request_json = request.get_json()
        video_url = request_json['video_url']
        resolution = request_json['resolution']

        # Download the video from the URL with streaming
        video_filename = '/tmp/input_video.mp4'
        with requests.get(video_url, stream=True) as response:
            response.raise_for_status()
            with open(video_filename, 'wb') as video_file:
                for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=8192):
                    video_file.write(chunk)

        # Generate a unique output filename based on the current timestamp
        timestamp = datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
        output_filename = f'/tmp/output_video_{timestamp}.mp4'

        # Crop the video using MoviePy
        crop_video(video_filename, output_filename, resolution)

        # Upload the cropped video to Google Cloud Storage in chunks
        bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
        blob = bucket.blob(os.path.basename(output_filename))

        with open(output_filename, 'rb') as video_file:
            chunk_size = 5 * 1024 * 1024  # 5MB chunk size
            while True:
                chunk = video_file.read(chunk_size)
                if not chunk:
                    break
                blob.upload_from_string(chunk, content_type='video/mp4')

        # Generate the GCS URL for the cropped video
        gcs_url = f'https://storage.googleapis.com/{bucket_name}/{blob.name}'

        return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'body': json.dumps({
                'output_url': gcs_url
            })
        }

    except Exception as e:
        error_message = f"Error: {str(e)}\n{traceback.format_exc()}"
        print(error_message)
        return {
            'statusCode': 500,
            'body': json.dumps({
                'error': error_message
            })
        }


I tried invoking this function through api, but it errored out with the error
{"body":"{"error": "Error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe\n\nMoviePy error: FFMPEG encountered the following error while writing file output_video_20240506140707TEMP_MPY_wvf_snd.mp4:\n\nb'output_video_20240506140707TEMP_MPY_wvf_snd.mp4: Read-only file system\\n'\n\nIn case it helps, make sure you are using a recent version of FFMPEG (the versions in the Ubuntu/Debian repos are deprecated).\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/moviepy/audio/io/ffmpeg_audiowriter.py\", line 74, in write_frames\n    self.proc.stdin.write(frames_array.tobytes())\nBrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe\n\nDuring handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:\n\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/workspace/main.py\", line 57, in crop\n    crop_video(video_filename, output_filename, resolution)\n  File \"/workspace/main.py\", line 36, in crop_video\n    cropped_clip.write_videofile(output_path, codec=\"libx264\", audio_codec=\"aac\", threads=5, preset=\"ultrafast\")\n  File \"\", line 2, in write_videofile\n  File \"/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/moviepy/decorators.py\", line 54, in requires_duration\n    return f(clip, *a, **k)\n           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\n  File \"\", line 2, in write_videofile\n  File \"/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/moviepy/decorators.py\", line 135, in use_clip_fps_by_default\n    return f(clip, *new_a, **new_kw)\n           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\n  File \"\", line 2, in write_videofile\n  File \"/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/moviepy/decorators.py\", line 22, in convert_masks_to_RGB\n    return f(clip, *a, **k)\n           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\n  File \"/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/moviepy/video/VideoClip.py\", line 293, in write_videofile\n    self.audio.write_audiofile(audiofile, audio_fps,\n  File \"\", line 2, in write_audiofile\n  File \"/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/moviepy/decorators.py\", line 54, in requires_duration\n    return f(clip, *a, **k)\n           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\n  File \"/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/moviepy/audio/AudioClip.py\", line 206, in write_audiofile\n    return ffmpeg_audiowrite(self, filename, fps, nbytes, buffersize,\n           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\n  File \"\", line 2, in ffmpeg_audiowrite\n  File \"/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/moviepy/decorators.py\", line 54, in requires_duration\n    return f(clip, *a, **k)\n           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\n  File \"/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/moviepy/audio/io/ffmpeg_audiowriter.py\", line 170, in ffmpeg_audiowrite\n    writer.write_frames(chunk)\n  File \"/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/moviepy/audio/io/ffmpeg_audiowriter.py\", line 117, in write_frames\n    raise IOError(error)\nOSError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe\n\nMoviePy error: FFMPEG encountered the following error while writing file output_video_20240506140707TEMP_MPY_wvf_snd.mp4:\n\nb'output_video_20240506140707TEMP_MPY_wvf_snd.mp4: Read-only file system\\n'\n\nIn case it helps, make sure you are using a recent version of FFMPEG (the versions in the Ubuntu/Debian repos are deprecated).\n"}","statusCode":500}
